# One-step ahead forecasts in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm using a `forecast` function in R many times with loop (12 months) for but I want to use accuracy to compare forecast for horizon time =12 and one-step ahead. My problem is how to store the results of 12 times to use it in accuracy.

```
for (i in 1:12) { 
  demfit <- ets(Dem2) 
  f <- forecast(demfit, 1) 
  Dem2[length(Dem2)+1] <- f$mean[1] 
} 
accuracy(f,Test)
```

it computes accuracy only for the last point forecast 12

But, I'm looking to this for the 12 forecats as this :

```
fit <- ets(Dem2) 
f1 <- forecast(fit, 12) 
accuracy(f1, Test)
```

Comment: On a separate note, where do forecast and accuracy come from? which package?

Comment: Forecast package. Is that your question?

Comment: Yep thanks, but that was the less important comment.

Comment: Dem2 is my training and Test is my test. What I'm looking to do is to compare between forecasting for an horizon=12 and forecasting by one-step ahead (12 times) such as, at each time I update my time serie with the forecasted value. So, to do this, I should store the output at each time in a vector and then apply the accuracy function

Comment: I meant that my first comment was the important in order to get answers.....

Comment: Yes, I saw the link so I triyed to explain my problem. I didn't understand where is the issue in my post?

Comment: Now, I understand what you have said at the begining. I totaly ignore it.
Thank you for this information

Comment: :) That's fine. And this way you have received additional reputation and are now able to vote up as well. I will have a look at your problem on this question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. By the way, I tried to stored in a vector, matrix, list but it doesn't work

Comment: Is it the `f` variable that you want to essentially have 12 values when the loop is over?

Comment: Yes, I want to have 12 values at the end of the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is essentially store 12 values in the `f` list and also in the `accuracy` list when the loop will have finished.

The way to do it is the following (to save it in a list):

```
f     <- list()
for (i in 1:12) { 
  demfit <- ets(Dem2) 
  f[[i]] <- forecast(demfit, 1)  #start filling the f list with values
  Dem2[length(Dem2)+1] <- f$mean[1]
} 
f <- unlist(f)
accuracy(f,Test)
```

And `f` will essentially be a list containing 12 values, one for each iteration. Same for `myacc`.

Comment: If this is not what you were expecting, just let me know of what you would like the outcome to be and I will help.

Comment: I tried to do this but I get this error for the accuracy
`> accuracy(f,Test)
Error in testaccuracy(f, x, test, d, D) : Unknown list structure
In addition: Warning message:
In trainingaccuracy(f, test, d, D) : test elements must be within sample`

I corrected this :
`Dem2[length(Dem2)+1] <- f[[1]]$mean[1]`

Comment: I think then what you really want to do is to make a list with the accuracies and not with the f values. Try this and you will get a list of the 12 accuracies. If you want both just create 2 lists and do the same.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with how the functions `accuracy` work but in order to save elements in a list in a loop this is the way to go. If you want to make your process work then you need to explain to me how these functions work or specify an example outside the loop that worked.

Comment: I need to go for now but i will help when I get back. Let me know as much of the problem as possible.

Comment: Here is an example: 
Case 1 : Forecast horizon = 12
`fit<-ets(Dem2)
f1<-forecast(fit,12)`
accuracy(f1,Test)

Comment: So, essentially the forecast horizon is `i`. Check the updated answer. This should be it. I am saving the accuracy in the list `myacc` and the forecast values in the `f` list.

Comment: forecast horizon is always 1 (one-step ahead). I tried your updated answer but I got this error : `Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'` (I think a problem in accuracy). I'm looking to have this output :    `Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
Jan 2012       230.3243 223.8919 236.6268 220.6393 239.8659
Feb 2012       229.8866 222.4213 237.3541 218.5189 241.0911
Mar 2012       229.4638 221.1358 238.1002 216.5982 242.6176
...` at the end of the boucle (when i=12)

Comment: Oh ok. Then the code is the same. I just replaced `i` with `1`. I updated the answer.

Comment: I think I know what you need. Try the above.

Comment: What I need is to get the accuracy of the whole vector(12 forecasts) not 12 seperatly. Your answer give me the accuracy of each forecast value but not of the 12

Comment: I got this error `Warning message:
In trainingaccuracy(f, test, d, D) : test elements must be within sample`. I don't understand what's the problem because my Test is within sample

Comment: By the way, I found this error in the link below [link](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/master/R/errors.R)

Comment: Yeah the error seems to be coming from `else if(min(test) < 1 | max(test) > n)` but i cannot help with this since I do not have your data. Has the above code solved your initial question? For your new error I suggest you post a new question to get an answer from someone who knows how to work with `accuracy`

Comment: This error says that if any element in your test set is less than 1 or if any element is greater than n then give the warning...

Comment: Yes, it says exactly this. Your answer solved my problem. the error just a warning. As you say, I will post a new question about that.
Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome Maya! I am glad I could help. I hope you will find the answer. And to give you some advice, if you provide just a subset of your data to your new question I guarantee you will get a correct answer. It is always easier for us to work with data.

Comment: I will add this in my question. Thank you for  your advice